# Boot Windows 10 on connection to outlet

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've been looking in to Smart Home Devices and what have you. Specifically, "Smart" Outlets that can be powered on remotely. I wanted to know - would it be possible to configure Windows 10 (Or my Bios, I suppose) such that my desktop would boot as soon as it's connected to power?

If not, is there a way I could achieve a similar result? I'm effectively trying to power on my desktop remotely when it's completely shutdown, not in hibernation or sleep mode.

Comment: Its possible to configure computers to be enabled when LAN activity is detected.  Its called Wake On Lan.  What is possible depends on the hardware being used though.  Based on the information provided its not possible to determine if your hardware supports Wake On Lan or if the outlet your looking at supports it.

Comment: Like Ramhound said, a possible solution would be to turn on the outlet, and then send a Wake On Lan packet to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most BIOS have a function allowing you to choose whether or not to power the computer on when it is connected to power.

This is commonly used for computers that run in remote locations so that they'll power themselves back up after a power outage occurs.

Check inside your computer BIOS for a setting or section under Power Management called "AC Power Recovery" or something similar, and if it is there, set it to the setting that will turn it on when power is returned to the computer.